# Install Debian kernel header files 3.4.90+ via terminal for ARMHF

Tags: linux, debian, kernel, header-file

I am trying to install the kernel header files on Debian via the terminal,
but it does not seem to exist in `apt-get`.

The reason I need the kernel header files is because I need to
install WiFi adapter drivers for an RTL wifi chip, and when running
the `install.sh` that comes with the drivers it ends with
an error that says that it can not find `build` in `/lib/modules/3.4.90+/`.

I have read articles that suggest that I need to compile and build the kernel from scratch but that seems a bit unnecessary to me.

I have also tried `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)` but an lower version of the kernel is installed instead.

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

**EDIT:**

I'm on ARM Debian and the WiFi module uses a RTL8188 chip.

I downloaded the Linux image from www.armhf.com

Comment: btw, what model realtik nic is it?  it may be supported in a later version of the mainline kernel.

Comment: I updated the question.

Comment: Sorry, i know very little about arm hardware...and amongst what little i do know is that there is not much consistency or standardisation in arm linux devices, every manufacturer does things differently.  your best best is to google for your device's brand and model with 'linux kernel'.  BTW, if you downloaded the linux image from www.armhf.com, do they also have the matching kernel source or headers?  or an updated version with RTL8188 support?

Comment: BTW, is there any particular reason why you downloaded and installed a kernel from www.armhf.com?  Can you revert back to the stock debian kernel?  If you could then you could install the matching linux-headers-* package as in my answer.

Comment: is your device an odroid xu?  that's the only device on www.armhf.com that has even close to a 3.4.90 kernel (all the others have 3.10.17 or 3.14.4.1).....and for the odroid xu they have linux image and headers for 3.4.91.1 - if your device is an adroid, try upgrading to that and installing the headers at the same time.  http://www.armhf.com/boards/odroid-xu/#wheezy

Comment: Well, it seems as if the Wheezy image I downloaded has no kernel to begin with as per their definition on the website. The board I am using is an Olimex Olinuxino A10 with 4GB NAND Flash. It is the only board with that cheap of a CPU. According to many people it is not possible to boot to Debian from NAND but I managed to get it to work and Ethernet works fine, all I need now is WiFi and SATA. To install WiFi I need to have kernel 3.4.90+ apparently. I am very new to this deep stuff of Linux, but I really need to learn these things. I have read more about this and maybe I should...

Comment: ...just compile my own kernel with the proper modules and drivers. There's Linux Sunxi for that that supports the CPU model and WiFi as well as SATA and everything else, but even they mention that NAND booting to Linux should not be possible with the CPU that I am using, but I did get it to work using the No-Kernel image from armhf.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I had to do was to copy the folder `3.4.90+` in the path `/lib/modules` from the original Olimex Debian Image to the same path on the NAND flash.

After that I just installed `firmware-realtek` and `wpa_supplicant` and I was up and running.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a stock debian kernel or a custom-compiled kernel?  If stock, there should be a matching linux-headers-* package for your linux-image-* package.

Debian also has virtual packages called `linux-image-$arch` and `linux-headers-$arch` (e.g. where `$arch` is `amd64` or `586` or `686-pae` etc) that depend on the most recent available kernel packages so if your system is `amd64` then

`apt-get install linux-image-amd64 linux-headers-amd64`

will install the most recent kernel image and headers for your version of debian.

The same is true if you are using kernels from the [Liquorix](http://www.liquorix.net/) repository, but the virtual packages have slightly different names:

`apt-get install  linux-image-liquorix-amd64 linux-headers-liquorix-amd64`

Note that for realtek NICs you will probably also need to install the realtek firmware from the non-free section of the debian archives.  Make sure that `non-free` is in your `/etc/apt/sources.list` and run

```
apt-get install firmware-realtek
```

---

Finally, to compile modules you will probably also need the `dkms` package or at least the `build-essential` package installed.

Comment: sorry, its for ARM. Not intel or AMD.

Comment: I updated the question.

Comment: Btw I think it's a custom kernel. I downloaded it from www.armhf.com but it says "Root File System (No kernel)"